# PHP - session_start()

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP page that has session_start() at the very top. Halfway through the page, if a certain condition is met, the page is reloaded using JavaScript. I'm wondering if session_start() is called again when the page is reloaded or does PHP know to skip it since the session has already started?

Answer (score 1):

[session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) — Start new or resume existing session. Starts a new session if not started else resumes the existing session.

**Added**
You could check and initiate, like:

```
if (session_id() == "") {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: That page says, "As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. **Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.**"

Comment: @Bryan as per your question, since you already have session_start() at top of page so if you have second session_start() somewhere in mid of page, that will get ignored and your previous session will resume..

Comment: but yes you'll get an error notice, since calling it multiple times does not make sense